# What will be the correct query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to figure out how my query should look like.

With this query i `select * from usr_time_reg`
`WHERE usr_time_nr = '$usr_time_nr' AND usr_stamp_in LIKE '$y_m'`

So far, so good!
Now i'd like to also select `usr_stamp_in WHERE usr_stamp_in = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND usr_stamp_out = '$y_m`

How should that query look like?
Query downunder is selecting ALL `usr_stamp_in` that contains '0000-00...'
 I still need the filtering with "time_nr & y_m"!

```
//Make the Select in mysql
$query = "SELECT * FROM usr_time_reg
                   WHERE usr_time_nr = '$usr_time_nr' AND usr_stamp_in LIKE '$y_m'
                   OR usr_stamp_in = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND usr_stamp_out LIKE '$y_m'
                   ORDER BY usr_stamp_in DESC";
```

Variables

```
$y_m = "2015-03%";
$time_nr = "1";
```

**db**

```
ID  time_nr        stamp_in                stamp_out
1    1        2015-03-03 06:00:00     2015-03-03 15:30:00
2    1        0000-00-00 00:00:00     2015-03-04 15:30:00
3    1        2015-03-03 06:00:00     0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Comment: Please show sample data and expected output so that we understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Re-read marcusadam's comment. Where's time_nr in the output? Where's stamp_out in the input? Not making a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of `$row['stamp_in']` to see what's happening, try to understand why doesn't echo anything, and then act consequently.

Comment: $Marcus Adams: The problem is that my query only selects rows in "stamp_in" LIKE $y_m (2015-03%). Here i like to add a select, to list ALL "stamp_out" with "stamp_in" LIKE $y_m.

Comment: "In other words i like to echo the data just like it looks in db." Makes no sense. Just like in your DB would be just `SELECT * FROM Table;` Can you try to say what you are really looking for, like... Records where `stamp_in = $time_nr` or records where `stamp_out = $time_nr`? You say your query will only echo 1 and 3, but which query are you talking about. You have two listed. This is probably an easy to solve question, but it's just not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everything you are wanting to do can be done down in the WHERE statement.

My best guess is:

```
SELECT *
FROM usr_time_reg
WHERE 
    usr_time_nr = '$usr_time_nr'
    AND
    (
        usr_stamp_in LIKE '$y_m'    
        OR
        (
            usr_stamp_in = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
            AND 
            usr_stamp_out = '$y_m'
        )
    );
```

Here `usr_time_nr` will always have to be `'$user_time_nr'` and then either one of the conditions seperated by OR will need to be true.